# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, where $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\frac12 a_n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

*Note: A similar question (same recursive function) has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142306/sequence-a-n1-sqrt1-frac12a-n2), but none of the answers is relevant to my question.*

---

I am trying to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. The sequence $a_n$ is given by the recursive  function $$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\frac12 a_n}$$ with $$a_1 =0$$

---

- I proved using induction that the monotonicity is: $a_n \nearrow$
- and that the upper bound is $a_n> \sqrt{2}$

---

**Theorem 1**

> If $a_n$ is monotonous and bounded then it converges, thus its limit exists

**Theorem 2**

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = M$ then every subsequence has the same limit.

---

Therefore applying limit to $(1)$:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\frac12 a_n} \iff M = \sqrt{1+\frac12 \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n} \iff M^2 = 1 +\frac{M}{2} \iff $$

$$ \boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = M=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}} $$

---

[This value of the limit is smaller than the upper bound](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%7D%7B4%7D%3C%5Csqrt%7B2%7D) $\sqrt{2}$ and this concerns me.

Does this fact mean that the upper bound I've found is **some upper bound**  but not the **supremum** or did I make a mistake in calculating the limit?

---

**Edit: Upper bound proof**

We will prove by induction that $a_n < \sqrt{2}$.

- For $n=1$: $a_2 = \sqrt{1 +\frac12 1} < \sqrt{2}$
- For $n=k$: Let $a_k < \sqrt{2}$
- For $n=k+1:$ $a_{k+1} = \sqrt{1 + \frac12 a_k} < \sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac1{\sqrt{2}}}< \sqrt{2}$

Hence indeed $a_n < \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Your upper bound seems to be wrong, by considering the first terms of your sequence...

Comment: @BastienTourand Just edited with a proof of the upper bound

Comment: An upper bound is not the *least* upper bound.

Comment: Your sequence is not the same as the one in the link you gave.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I messed up... It is actually and I got confused. So sorry for that...

Comment: You write:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\frac12 a_n}$$
You should apply the limit to both sides already here, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\frac12 a_n}$$
Then you can write
$$M = \sqrt{1+\frac12 M}$$

Comment: @md2perpe Correct. Thank you. I forgot to add a square to my question, everything works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's just an upper bound, not a supremum. Indeed, you can prove that the sequence is no terms exceed $\frac{3}{2}$ by induction. We have $a_2 = \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{2}}<\sqrt{1+ \frac{5}{4}}=\frac{3}{2} $. Assume that $a_n < \frac{3}{2}$, it still holds for $a_{n+1}$:
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\frac{a_n}{2}} < \sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4}} < \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{3}{2}$$
Moreover, in various Calculus 1 textbooks, you can easily find that if $\{a\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ exists, the sumpremum of $\{a\}_{n\geq 1}$ is the limit of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L = \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}$. Then $L^2 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}L$ and $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{2}L} = L$.

Let us use the mathematical induction to prove: $0 < a_n < a_{n+1} < L$ for all $n \ge 2$.

For $n = 2$, it is easy to verify it.

Assume that the inequality is true for $n = k$ ($k\ge 2$), i.e., $0 < a_k < a_{k+1} < L$.
Let us prove that the inequality is also true for $n = k + 1$, i.e., $0 < a_{k+1} < a_{k+2} < L$.

First, since $a_{k+1} < L$, we have $a_{k+2} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{2}a_{k+1}} < \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{2}L} = L$.

Second, since $0 < a_{k+1} < L$ and $L > \frac{1}{2}$, we have $(a_{k+1} - L)(a_{k+1} + L - \frac{1}{2}) < 0$
that is $a_{k+1}^2 - \frac{1}{2}a_{k+1} - 1 < 0$ (using $L^2 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}L$), which results in
$a_{k+2} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{2}a_{k+1}} > a_{k+1}$. This completes the proof.

$\phantom{2}$

Thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ exists (finite). Let $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = M > 0$.
Taking limit on both sides of $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{2}a_n}$, we have
$M = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{2}M}$ which results in $M = \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}$. We are done.